# Set values access in constructor

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce, set

I have a Set populated in a method. I need the values in the contructor so that each time load those values are static. Can I do that?

**Method**

```
 public List<SelectOption> getValue()
     {  ProdIDs = new Set<ID>();
         List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();
         option.add(new selectoption('none','---Select--'));
         for(My_Setup_Products_vod__c  ac: [Select Id,Product_vod__r.Name,Ownerid,Name From My_Setup_Products_vod__c where Ownerid=:Userinfo.getUserId()])
         {

           for(Product_vod__c c: [Select Id,Name From Product_vod__c where Parent_Product_vod__c=:ac.Product_vod__c ])      
            {  if(c!=null){
                 ProdIds.add(c.ID);
                 }




             option.add(new SelectOption(c.ID,c.Name));
            }


         }


         return option;    


    }
```

I need ProdIds ( which in a Set of IDs public get set done already) to be there in constructor also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you need to achieve what you are after, you have to do some refactoring:

1. Remove the SOQL query of the second for loop. Inside the first loop create a list which will be populated by My_Setup_Products__c
2. Remove the if checking inside the 2nd for loop, it's redundant. If no records are returned, the code will not execute the for loop
3. Take your set out of the existing method and make it a property of the controller. The set will be populated by the constructor and then you will use your method to return the variable if you need so.